# How can I read one integer each time?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm using an assembly library to make a program that reads three integers from standard input. When the reading is done in the console it works perfectly, but when I use a file as input, it reads the three integers at once.

This is the strace for console:

```
read(0, "3000\n", 512)                  = 5
read(0, "2000\n", 512)                  = 5
read(0, "1000\n", 512)                  = 5
```

And this from input file:

```
read(0, "3000\n2000\n1000\n", 512)      = 15
read(0, "", 512)                        = 0
read(0, "", 512)                        = 0
```

Here are the procedures:

```
;--------------------------------------------------------
ReadInt:
;
; Reads a 32-bit signed decimal integer from standard
; input, stopping when the Enter key is pressed.
; All valid digits occurring before a non-numeric character
; are converted to the integer value. Leading spaces are
; ignored, and an optional leading + or - sign is permitted.
; All spaces return a valid integer, value zero.
; Receives: nothing
; Returns:  If CF=0, the integer is valid, and EAX = binary value.
;   If CF=1, the integer is invalid and EAX = 0.
;--------------------------------------------------------

    push edx
    push ecx
; Input a signed decimal string.

    mov   edx,digitBuffer
    mov   ecx,MAX_DIGITS
    call  ReadString
    mov   ecx,eax   ; save length in ECX

; Convert to binary (EDX -> string, ECX = length)

    call    ParseInteger32  ; returns EAX, CF

    pop ecx
    pop edx
    ret
;--------------- End of ReadInt ------------------------

;--------------------------------------------------------
ReadString:
;
; Reads a string from the keyboard and places the characters
; in a buffer.
; Receives: EDX offset of the input buffer
;           ECX = maximum characters to input (including terminal null)
; Returns:  EAX = size of the input string.
; Comments: Stops when Enter key (0Dh,0Ah) is pressed. If the user
; types more characters than (ECX-1), the excess characters
; are ignored.
; Written by Kip Irvine and Gerald Cahill
; Modified by Curtis Wong
;--------------------------------------------------------
    enter 8, 0    ; bufSize: ebp - 4
              ; bytesRead: ebp - 8
    pushad

    mov edi,edx     ; set EDI to buffer offset
    mov dword [ebp - 4],ecx     ; save buffer size

    call ReadKeys

    mov dword [ebp - 8], eax

    cmp eax,0
    jz  .L5         ; skip move if zero chars input

    cld     ; search forward
    mov ecx, dword [ebp - 4]    ; repetition count for SCASB
    dec ecx
    mov al,NL   ; scan for 0Ah (Line Feed) terminal character
    repne scasb
    jne .L1     ; if not found, jump to L1

    ;if we reach this line, length of input string <= (bufsize - 2)

    dec dword [ebp - 8]     ; second adjustment to bytesRead
    dec edi         ; 0Ah found: back up two positions
    cmp edi,edx         ; don't back up to before the user's buffer
    jae .L2
    mov edi,edx         ; 0Ah must be the only byte in the buffer
    jmp .L2     ; and jump to L2

.L1:    mov edi,edx     ; point to last byte in buffer
    add edi,dword [ebp - 4]
    dec edi
    mov byte [edi],0            ; insert null byte

    ; Clear excess characters from the buffer, 1 byte at a time
.L6:    call BufferFlush
    jmp .L5

.L2:    mov byte [edi],0        ; insert null byte

.L5:    popad
    mov eax, dword [ebp - 8]
    leave
    ret
;--------------- End of ReadString --------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aaron points out, the problem is that `sys_read` behaves differently when `stdin` is redirected. You could fix it as he suggests. or you could use Along32's `ReadString` and use a "homemade" `atoi`.

```
;--------------------
atoi:
    push ebx

    mov edx, [esp + 8]  ; pointer to string
    xor ebx, ebx ; assume not negative

    cmp byte [edx], '-'
    jnz notneg
    inc ebx ; indicate negative
    inc edx ; move past the '-'
notneg:

    xor eax, eax        ; clear "result"
.top:
    movzx ecx, byte [edx]
    inc edx
    cmp ecx, byte '0'
    jb .done
    cmp ecx, byte '9'
    ja .done

    ; we have a valid character - multiply
    ; result-so-far by 10, subtract '0'
    ; from the character to convert it to
    ; a number, and add it to result.

    lea eax, [eax + eax * 4]
    lea eax, [eax * 2 + ecx - '0']

    jmp short .top
.done:
    test ebx, ebx
    jz notminus
    neg eax
notminus:
    pop ebx
    ret
;------------------------
```

That expects the address of the string to be pushed on the stack and "removed" after, but I think you could just comment out that second line, and pass the address in edx (not tested!). More like the rest of the Along32 code that way. Unlike Along32's code, it returns with edx pointed to the next byte, and ecx (just cl, really) containing the "invalid" byte that stopped processing. I think you could call it repeatedly on the string returned by `ReadString`, saving the integer (in eax) and calling it again (without touching edx) if ecx is LF. When ecx is zero, you're done. Hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to buffer the input and split it because the console and files behave slightly different. A console will send you data as soon as someone presses <kbd>Return</kbd>, that is line by line.

Files will send you as much data as possible per call to `read()`.

To make your code work, you will have to write a `readline()` function that reads the input byte by byte and returns when it sees a line feed.

Or you can use an internal buffer, fill it with as much data as possible, find the first line, return that, repeat until the buffer is empty, try to read more data, return EOF when there is no more data from the input.